# How to keep only the last index in groups of rows where a condition is met in pandas?

Tags: pandas, filtering, multiple-conditions

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

```
d = {'value': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 'flag_1': [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],'flag_2':[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],'index':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I need to perform the following filter on it:
If flag 1 and flag 2 are equal keep the row with the maximum index from the consecutive indices. Below for rows 4,5,6 and rows 9,10 flag 1 and flag 2 are equal. From the group of consecutive indices 4,5,6 therefore I wish to keep only row 6 and drop rows 4 and 5. For the next group of rows 9 and 10 I wish to keep only row 10. The rows where flag 1 and 2 are not equal should all be retained. I want my final output to look as shown below:

[image]

I am really not sure how to achieve what is required so I would be grateful for any advice on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can compare consecutive rows with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). This solution requires a sorted index.

```
In [5]: df[~df[['flag_1', 'flag_2']].eq(df[['flag_1', 'flag_2']].shift(-1)).all(axis=1)]
Out[5]: 
   value  flag_1  flag_2  index
0      1       0       1      1
1      1       1       0      2
2      1       0       1      3
5      1       1       1      6
6      1       0       1      7
7      1       1       0      8
9      1       1       1     10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd: pd.DataFrame):
    return dd if len(dd)==1 else dd.tail(1)

col1=df[['flag_1','flag_2']].astype(str).apply("".join,axis=1)
col2 = col1.ne(col1.shift()).cumsum()
df.groupby(col2,group_keys=False).apply(function1)
```

out：

```
   value  flag_1  flag_2  index
0      1       0       1      1
1      1       1       0      2
2      1       0       1      3
5      1       1       1      6
6      1       0       1      7
7      1       1       0      8
9      1       1       1     10
```